# No NgModule metadata found for 'Fy', Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

This question is similar to

[No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'" after Upgrade to Angular 5.1.0 and AngularCli 1.6.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798)

Or, many of the other "No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'" questions.

But, seems to be more specific. I only get the following error when I publish to a web server. The program runs fine when published to my local machine and when built in development mode.

Instead of no metadata found for 'AppModule', it reports no metadata found for 'Cm' or 'Fy'.

Other people were saying that might be an issue with Webpack, but I couldn't find any solution. I've tried updating my npm packages, deleting them all, clearing the cache, and reinstalling.

```
    GET https://dev.celinainsurance.com/styles.52c5d139a2a0d528a6bd.css 404 ()
    3 GET https://dev.celinainsurance.com/polyfills.16c7192dd87d7bd6ba49.js 404 ()
    main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'Fy'.
        at e.resolve (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e.getNgModuleMetadata (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e._loadModules (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e._compileModuleAndComponents (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e.compileModuleAsync (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e.compileModuleAsync (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at e.bootstrapModule (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at Object.zUnb (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
        at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
        at Object.4 (main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1)
    e.resolve @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e.getNgModuleMetadata @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e._loadModules @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e._compileModuleAndComponents @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e.compileModuleAsync @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e.compileModuleAsync @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    e.bootstrapModule @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    zUnb @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    p @ runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1
    4 @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
    p @ runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1
    n @ runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1
    e @ runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1
    (anonymous) @ main.d7aa191a672411cff0f3.js:1
```

**Any** help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need to see more code. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read and followed [these guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for deployment?

Comment: I read through the article. Thanks for the info! I rebuilt the project and did a few things different and now its working. Not sure what change fixed it. I will investigate it later, and hopefully post the answer so everyone can see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found my error. I decided to create a new angular project and to repetitively publish it as I added npm packages, to see when the error would occur. When I looked up a tutorial on how to migrate my new project from angular 5 to 6, I followed the steps found here:
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-5-app-angular-6-visual-studio-2017/

When I compared my old project to the working new one, I noticed two major differences. One was that when I had migrated my old project to angular 6, I had missed this step:

"Once this is done, remove rxjs-compat. This package is required to get backwards compatibility with RxJS previous to version 6. But, it is no longer required now, so let’s remove it using the following command: "

```
npm uninstall rxjs-compat
```

-- TalkingDotNet

I believe that was the major cause of the error. The other major difference I found was a segment of unnecessary code which probably didn't cause the problem, but I'm going to mention anyway just in case.

I had accidentally duplicated this line of code, in my main.ts file.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The lines of code looked slightly different, so I hadn't noticed the duplication.